# How can I get my own phone number from an iPhone running iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to get my own phone number but I can not find it. This is available in jailbroken phones and iOS 7 and lower versions. Please any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to **settings** > **phone**

First line is **My Number**

Answer (score 4):

You can do one of the followings in order to find your phone number.

- First, If you have enabled **My Number** feature in your iPhone Settings before, you can see your number in the Phone app, the top row.
- Second, If you jailbroke the device before, you can use Cydia tweaks when possible.
- Finally, the most popular way is to call your friend's iPhone. He can see your phone number and he can tell you the number. That is your own number.

**NOTE:** The last way is only possible if you have enabled **Show my Caller ID** in Settings -> Phone.